# Missing external cookie on Xamarin.Forms with ASP.NET MVC & OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, oauth-2.0, owin

I've got a Web API written with ASP.NET MVC 5 (Auth Template) which uses Facebook Authentication with OWIN Middleware. The Web API is used by a Xamarin.Forms app. The Facebook authentication Workflow on the app side is implemented through the Xamarin.Auth library.

So far so good. Unfortunately on the Xamarin app the external cookie gets lost after authentication. The backend (API) is setting all claims correctly and when it goes back to the GetExternalLogin method, the external cookie is missing. As the cookie is not set, it tries to set the claims again and again and finally I've got a too many redirects error on the app. If I perform the same request from the app in Chrome or Firefox on my PC, the external cookie will be set and everything is working correctly. Furthermore I don't believe it's related to the Xamarin.Auth library, as it's even not working if i try to fire the same REST call in chrome on android.

I'm aware, that there are some issues with Cookies set by OWIN and others set by ASP.NET, but that shouldn't be a problem here, as it's working on a desktop client.

On the app as well as on the backend I'm using the latest nuget packages.

I really appreciate any kind of help as I really don't know what it could be.

Comment: What happens if you use the device's browser? (like you stated you did testing it with a desktop browser)

Comment: I already tried that on Android (Chrome) & iOS (Safari), but I still don't get an external cookie, only a correlation id from facebook. As the backend is the same server for mobile & desktop, maybe a wrong configuration on facebook OAuth?